# Castle Windsor Reference Documentation

Tags: documentation, castle-windsor

Is there any reference (msdn-like: interfaces, classes, methods, properties, ...) documentation for `Castle Windsor`?

I was trying to find something on `github` and [http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/](http://castleproject.org), but all links seem to point to github's ["verbose doc"](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/tree/master/docs), which does not fulfill the reference needs.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, all I find are mini how-to articles, some very old, some very general.